# Unexpected undefined return value from a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an unexpected undefined return value from a function.

```
function createselbox(arr) {
    console.log('In createselbox');
    var startstr = `Something`;
    mytemp = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        mytemp = mytemp + '<option>' + arr[i] + '</option>';
    }
    var ret = startstr + mytemp + `Something else    `;
    IsStaff = CheckifStaff();
    console.log('Checkifstaff is ' + IsStaff);
    if (IsStaff) {
        console.log('Got true createselbox');
        console.log('In sel loop');
        ret = startstr + mytemp + `Something more`;
    } else {
        console.log('Got false createselbox');
    }
    return ret;
}

function CheckifStaff() {
    var data = {
        "isstaff": 'check'
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "/functions/checkifstaff",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            var recdata = data;
            if (recdata.indexOf('Has add permissions') != -1) {
                console.log('Returning true');
                return 1;
            } else {
                console.log('Returning false');
                return 0;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured in CheckifStaff');
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

The console shows:

```
In createselbox
appointment.js ? dev = 96168005 : 292 Checkifstaff is undefined
appointment.js ? dev = 96168005 : 305 Got false createselbox
appointment.js ? dev = 96168005 : 158 Returning true
```

createselbox is called first. But the value from the function is being returned as false, apparently even before the function execution.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) You are returning to the `$.ajax` function, not returning something from CheckiStaff itself

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, why haven't you picked an answer yet? If not, why haven't you commented accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckifStaff()` has no explicit `return` statement, so it returns what all functions return by default, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, `CheckiStaff` needs to return something, here, for example CheckiStaff will return a Promise which's value is either 1 or 0. `createselbox` will now `await` `CheckiStaff` and then use the value it returns afterwards

```js
async function createselbox(arr) {
    console.log('In createselbox');
    var startstr = `Something`;
    mytemp = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        mytemp = mytemp + '<option>' + arr[i] + '</option>';
    }
    var ret = startstr + mytemp + `Something else    `;
    let IsStaff = await CheckiStaff();
    console.log('Checkifstaff is ' + IsStaff);
    if (IsStaff) {
        console.log('Got true createselbox');
        console.log('In sel loop');
        ret = startstr + mytemp + `Something more`;
    } else {
        console.log('Got false createselbox');
    }
    return ret;
}

function CheckifStaff() {
    var data = {
        "isstaff": 'check'
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "/functions/checkifstaff",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            var recdata = data;
            if (recdata.indexOf('Has add permissions') != -1) {
                console.log('Returning true');
                resolve(1);
            } else {
                console.log('Returning false');
                resolve(0);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured in CheckifStaff');
            resolve(0);
        }
    });
    });
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do change your ajax to be like this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "/functions/checkifstaff",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        var recdata = data;
        if (recdata.indexOf('Has add permissions') != -1) {
            console.log('Returning true');
            return 1;
        } else {
            console.log('Returning false');
            return 0;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('An error occured in CheckifStaff');
        return 0;
    }
}).then(function(data){
   return data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert, but i think when you use ajax you should wait for the response - use promise, or async/await func